# Is there a way to make changes in chrome dev tools and then test the page loading with those changes in lighthouse?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

I'm working on fixing a CLS issue. It would really speed up my development cycle if I was able to make HTML tweaks in the inspector, then be able to immediately run those through Lighthouse. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using local overrides to make changes persist in Chrome Dev Tools. Here's a video that explains it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNzOUOtnxDc&t=656s

I just deleted an unused CSS file full of fonts and compared the Lighthouse JSON files before and after and it seemed to work.

This is the Lighthouse comparison tool I used: https://googlechrome.github.io/lighthouse-ci/viewer/

This was the first time I did it, so apologies if it doesn't work as intended.

Hope this helps!